how to re-call initalState when change bottomtabnavigation with gorouter flutter?
When I start the application, I go to the home screen (call the home screen api) => switch to another tab (call that screen api) => go back to the home screen (currently not calling the api again)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You should be using didChangeDependencies to initialize or rebuild your bottomTabNavigation, not initState.
